# package doMC NOT available for R version 3.0.0 warning in install.packages

Tags: r, windows, install.packages, domc

For some packages like doMC & doSMP, i get the warning & inability to library(doMC).
As shown below, i have no problem with subselect thus no file/directory permission issue.
Also tried repo=http://cran.us.r-project.org & others, no luck.
please advise.

ps: for the unexpected Japanese characters, i have no clue; i assume that is a separable issue; no response yet from support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/6009-japanese-characters-show-unexpectedly

```
> install.packages('doMC')
Warning in install.packages :
  package 租oMC・is not available (for R version 3.0.0)
Installing package into 舛:/Users/YULE/Documents/R/win-library/3.0・(as 鼠ib・is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package 租oMC・is not available (for R version 3.0.0)
> install.packages('subselect')
Installing package into 舛:/Users/YULE/Documents/R/win-library/3.0・(as 鼠ib・is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/subselect_0.12-2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1295653 bytes (1.2 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 1.2 Mb

package 壮ubselect・successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\YULE\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6DK5mn\downloaded_packages
> library(subselect)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices datasets  stats     utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] subselect_0.12-2 XML_3.96-1.1     colorspace_1.2-2 RGtk2_2.20.25    rattle_2.6.26   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.0
```

Comment: Eh, it's not specific to R 3.0.0: I see `In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) : package ‘doMC’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available" warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-warning)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume it's not available to you because you're using Windows.  The `doMC` package has never been available on Windows because it depends on the `mclapply` function, before in the `multicore` package and now in `parallel`.  I haven't heard of any issues with `doMC` in R 3.0.0.

The `doSMP` package was intended to be the Windows alternative to `doMC`.  I believe it was eventually taken off CRAN because of problems building it on newer versions of GCC.

The `doParallel` and `doSNOW` packages are probably the most popular `foreach` backends available for Windows.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the constructive feedback; much appreciated; in Windows, for now, i gather one must use library(parallel) & avoid doMC/doSMP/multicore packages; this URL may be useful: onepager.togaware.com/Parallel.pdf

Comment: @YuLe: You could also try the `doParallel` or `doSNOW` packages.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to install it for windows, here it how you can:

```
install.packages("doMC", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

I did it for **R** 3.2.3 version and it works well.

As Erdogan mentioned, it works for R 4.x.x versions as well.

Comment: This may allow you to install and use doMC on Windows, but it won't execute in parallel. This is because doMC uses the `mclapply` function which is implemented with the `lapply` function on Windows.

Comment: May be. Yes. But I help a year back and since then there could have been developments in that package. :-)  yet, thanks for this update. may be user looking for the similar solution finds your comment to be helpful.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of doMC and R to verify that the Windows version is still sequential only. I also checked with Rich Calaway, the current maintainer of doMC, and he confirmed that doMC doesn't run in parallel on Windows.

Comment: Thank you.. saved my bacon for R 3.6.3! Works well on windows

Comment: `install.packages("doMC", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` worked well for R version 4.0.3. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with RTextTools, as RTextTools is now not available on CRAN.
I have Download RTextTools From Given Link

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RTextTools/

and copy RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz file in project root folder then run this command in project folder in terminal

"R CMD INSTALL RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz" 
After running this command I receive below error "ERROR: dependencies ‘SparseM’, ‘randomForest’, ‘tree’, ‘e1071’, ‘ipred’, ‘caTools’, ‘maxent’, ‘glmnet’, ‘tau’ are not available for package ‘RTextTools’"
Now install each dependencies from RStudio or RConsole (Any Editor used by you) by simply running this code

install.packages("caTools")

Install all 9 required packages One By One (In My Case it was 9 Packages Dependencies required by RTextTools) all packages will be installed except 'maxent'

Now download maxent from the given link

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/maxent/

and copy maxent_1.3.3.1.tar file in project folder then run this command in project folder in terminal

"R CMD INSTALL maxent_1.3.3.1.tar"

Now For RTextTools Run this command again in Terminal

"R CMD INSTALL RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz"

All is done Now..
But the Last Step is
Load the RTextTools using

library(RTextTools)

You will see one more Error: Load SparseM Now Loading SparseM use code below
library(SparseM)
and in the last Load RTextTools
library(RTextTools)