# Unable to install package 'doMC' on R 3.2.2

Tags: r, r-caret

I tried downloading doMC for Parallel Processing, but R version 3.2.2 doesn't support this package?

Comment: It does. What error message do you get?

Comment: [doMC only supports Unix-like OSes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/index.html), and I bet you're on Windows.

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘doMC’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [package doMC NOT available for R version 3.0.0 warning in install.packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453625/package-domc-not-available-for-r-version-3-0-0-warning-in-install-packages)